# Advanced Custom Fields wysiwyg in repeater

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In wordpress, I'm using the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://advancedcustomfields.com) plugin to create custom fields and I'm trying to put a wysiwyg editor in a repeater field.

**Here is my code:**

```
<? $args = array('post_type' => 'rates',);?>

<?php query_posts($args); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php $rates_col=get_field('rates'); ?>
    <? foreach( $rates_col as $rates_col_item){ ?>
        <div class="rate-item">
            <?php the_field('wysiwyg'); ?>
        </div>

    <? } ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php wp_reset_query()  ?>
```

Where `rates` is the repeater name, and `wysiwyg` is the wysiwyg editor subfield name. The repeater field is working, and if I have more than one repeater row, then `<div class="rate-item">` repeats to match it. But I don't see any of the content which I write in the editor. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is:
Your main field name is `rates`. And it contains any other subfields. When you create foreach loop, child fields in `rates` you need to call this way

```
<?php echo $rates_col_item['wysiwyg'];?>
```

And also, **try to avoid** `query_posts`, use `get_posts()`, `WP_Query` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In ACF repeater, for fetching the data below code is used.

```
get_sub_field('field_name');
```

The example link is : http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/